# Quit program run by GDB when terminate screen

Tags: gnu-screen, gdb

I am running my program using screen and GDB.
How I run my program:

```
screen -dmS adapter "./run-adapter.sh"
```

In `run-adapter.sh`

```
gdb -ex "handle SIGPIPE nostop noprint pass" -ex run -args ./Adapter adapter.conf
```

The problem is when I try to exit my program by screen:

```
screen -X -S adapter quit
```

The screen is terminated nicely, but the program and its GDB are still remaining (checked by `ps aux` command). Are there any ways to exit them when my screen is terminated?

**Edited:** As MarkPlotnick requested, my screen is `Screen version 4.00.03d (FAU) 23-Oct-06` and GDB is `GNU gdb (GDB) 7.7`.
Output of `grep Sig /proc/$(pgrep Adapter)/status`:

```
SigPnd: 0000000000040000
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: 0000000001001000
SigCgt: 0000000180000620
```

Comment: What happens when you kill as opposed to exit?

Comment: What happens if your script has the line `gdb -ex "handle SIGPIPE nostop noprint pass" -ex run -ex quit -args ./Adapter adapter.conf`

Comment: @RamanSailopal Yes I can kill the process and its GDB, but I am wondering is there any less ugly way.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thank you, it worked if I add "-ex quit". Can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I'd like to be able to explain in my answer why your program and gdb don't exit on their own when screen causes a SIGHUP to be sent to them. Can you tell us what version of gdb and screen you're using, and the output of `grep Sig /proc/$(pgrep Adapter)/status` ?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I have edited my question according to your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by MarkPlotnick's comment, I add `-ex quit` in gdb command and it worked in OpenSUSE 13.1. The full execution command is:

`gdb -ex "handle SIGPIPE nostop noprint pass" -ex run -ex quit -args ./Adapter adapter.conf`

And to quit screen with gdb automatically exit, I use:

`screen -X -S adapter quit`

Unfortunately, the same commands didn't work when I upgraded OS to OpenSUSE 42.2. After a little of investigating, now I can exit with:

`screen -X -S adapter stuff "^C"
 screen -X -S adapter quit`

The `stuff` command will send a Ctrl-C signal (SIGINT) to terminate the `adapter` process. After that we can quit normally by calling `screen ... quit`.

PS: The `-ex quit` option in gdb command isn't necessary anymore if we call `screen ... stuff`.